# Display array elements from array of objects using the index obtained from another mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux, action

As title suggest, I am trying to get object from an array using the index obtained from another separate array. I get error: Uncaught TypeError: venues[index].map is not a function.

```
venues = [
     {id: 4, title: "bro"}, {id: 5, title: "np bro"} 
   ]
   
   cityArray = [4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5]
```

Above is the venues and cityArray.

I get the index correctly. dispatches works correctly.

```
const Home = () => {
    const { city } = useParams();
  
    const featured = useSelector((state) => state.featuredList.featured);
   
    const venues = useSelector((state) => state.venueList.venues);

    useEffect(() => {   
        dispatch(listVenues())
    }, [dispatch])


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listFeatured())
    }, [dispatch])

  
    useEffect(() => {
        if (city === "perth") {
           setCityArray(featured?.featured_perth)
        }
    }, [featured, city]) 
    
    return (
        <GridWrapper>
            {cityArray?.map((i) => {
                 var index = venues?.findIndex(ar => parseInt(ar.id) === i);
                     return (
            
                        <div>
                          {venues[0].map(arr => 
                              (
                                <div>
                                   <h1>{arr.title}</h1>
                                </div>
                               )
                           )}
                        </div>    
                            )   
                        }
                            
                        
                        )}
        </GridWrapper>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: If you're going to do this a lot it makes sense to create a Map of venues which can simply be accessed by `id`. Even if you keep looking them up individually, you can simply use `find` instead of `findIndex` to return the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error `Uncaught TypeError: venues[index].map is not a function` is because `venues[index]` refers to an object not an array and objects don't implement a `map` method.

If you want to continue looking up each object individually, you can simply use `find()` instead of `findIndex()` to return the object itself. (You should probably be accounting for elements that aren't found as well).

```
return (
  <GridWrapper>
    {cityArray?.map((i) => {
      var venue = venues?.find((ar) => parseInt(ar.id) === i);
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{venue.title}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </GridWrapper>
);
```

But if you're going to be doing this repeatedly you should create a `Map` or object indexed by `id` and access it directly.

```
const venues = [
  { id: 4, title: "bro" },
  { id: 5, title: "np bro" }
];
const cityArray = [4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5];

const venueMap = new Map(venues.map(v => [v.id, v]));

return (
  <GridWrapper>
    {cityArray?.map((id) => {
      const venue = venueMap.get(id);
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{venue.title}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </GridWrapper>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `venues` is an array of objects, you should be able to access the title property with:

```
return (
    <GridWrapper>
      {cityArray?.map((i) => {
        var index = venues?.findIndex((ar) => parseInt(ar.id) === i);
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>{venues[index].title}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </GridWrapper>
  );
```